# ClamAV scan errors and warnings

Tags: terminal, antivirus, clamav

I ran a ClamAV scan on Mac OS (on Terminal) using this command:

```
clamscan -r --bell -i /
```

When it ran, this error appeared about 300 times:

```
LibClamAV Error: hfsplus_walk_catalog: failed to convert UTF-16BE to UTF-8
```

It also found these errors:

```
LibClamAV Warning: SWF: declared input length != compressed stream size, 894266992 != 9089007

LibClamAV Error: scanzws: LzmaInit() failed

LibClamAV Warning: cli_scanxz: decompress file size exceeds limits - only scanning 27262976 bytes

LibClamAV Error: cli_scanxz: premature end of compressed stream

LibClamAV Error: cli_scanxz: decompress error: 1

LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
```

I don't know what these errors mean. Why are all these errors appearing? Is the scan skipping over files? If so, then it might have skipped over infected files. Also, how serious are these errors, and what can be done to fix them?